# php xml http request returning error (403)

Tags: php, xml, request

Hi I am trying to use Expedias api hotel system and I can not seem to get it to work. Here is my code, I am getting this error:

```
<h1>403 Developer Inactive</h1>
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$ipad = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$usera = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

$url = "http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/info?'minorRev=5
&cid=55505
&apiKey=6spskr4y2sw4sh3vxkfg8cbg
&customerIpAddress = ".$ipad."
&customerUserAgent =".$usera."
&locale=en_US
&currencyCode=USD
&xml=<HotelInformationRequest>
<hotelId>122212</hotelId>
<options>HOTEL_SUMMARY</options>
</HotelInformationRequest>";

class cURL {

var $headers; 
var $user_agent; 
var $compression; 
var $cookie_file; 
var $proxy; 



function cURL($cookies=TRUE,$cookie='cookies.txt',$compression='gzip',$proxy=''){ 

$this->headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg'; 
$this->headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive'; 
$this->headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'; 
$this->user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)'; 
$this->compression=$compression; 
$this->proxy=$proxy; 
$this->cookies=$cookies; 

if ($this->cookies == TRUE) $this->cookie($cookie); 
} 


function cookie($cookie_file){ 
if (file_exists($cookie_file)){ 
$this->cookie_file=$cookie_file; 
} else { 
fopen($cookie_file,'w') or $this->error('The cookie file could not be opened. Make sure this directory has the correct permissions'); 
$this->cookie_file=$cookie_file; 
fclose($this->cookie_file); 
} 
} 


function get($url) { 
$process = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent); 
if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file); 
if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file); 
curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_ENCODING , $this->compression); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
if ($this->proxy) curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'proxy_ip:proxy_port'); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
$return = curl_exec($process); 
curl_close($process); 
return $return; 
} 


function post($url,$data) { 
$process = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent); 
if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file); 
if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_ENCODING , $this->compression); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
if ($this->proxy) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$return = curl_exec($process); 
curl_close($process); 
return $return; 
}

function error($error) { 
echo "<center><div style='width:500px;border: 3px solid #FFEEFF; padding: 3px; background-color: #FFDDFF;font-family: verdana; font-size: 10px'><b>cURL Error</b><br>$error</div></center>"; 
die; 
} 


function extractCustomHeader($start,$end,$header) { 
$pattern = '/'. $start .'(.*?)'. $end .'/'; 
if (preg_match($pattern, $header, $result)) { 
return $result[1]; 
} else { 
return false; 
} 
} 
}

$cc = new cURL();

$output = $cc->post($url,$postdata);
echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason why you would be getting a 403 Developer Inactive error is because your apiKey value is invalid, incorrect, or it has been disabled. If you already activated your account and this is the API key you were provided with - contact support.